# musical analysis with computer

Tags: analysis, characteristics

I am trying to analyze music from mp3 files. I want to get information regarding tempo, pitch, and other musical characteristics. How can I get this data? Is there open source software that gives me this information, or even better, a library?

Can anyone give me a hint on what to do or where to start looking?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[LibMAD](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) is an opensource mp3 decoder library that works really well. This will get you the 'raw' data of which to modify. To get pitch and some other 'characteristics' you will need to dive into the math.

Pitch is essentially the frequency of the sound. This can be done 'on' the fly (really in blocks of data) using FFTs. Pythons [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) has fft functions (if you're got the raw data). A library for fft's in c++ can be found [here.](http://www.fftw.org/)

Some 'math' behind an FFT can be found [here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch9.htm)

Tempo can also be calculated by applying some 2nd order Low Pass filters to the raw data then FFTing the data. Digital Filters are also discussed in the dspguide which is linked to above.

Good luck, its some good stuff but a lot of math if you're not ready for it.

Comment: Pitch is *not* essentially the same as frequency. Frequency is a physical measurement of one component of a sound. Pitch is a psychological *percept* of a complex sound. Pitch is related to the various frequencies and amplitudes in a complex sound, but it's a subtle and non-trivial relationship.

Comment: If you're trying to get to the exact defintion, then you are correct. But for purposes here, doing what I suggested will work to 'get the pitch' from mp3's (at a certain point). Using the ffts, you'd be able to pick off the peaks (which correnspond to certain notes), combine them in known ways (certain ratios create different pitchs) to get the pitch of a complex sound. Obviously have to know something about what you're trying to do, hence he 'should' have an understanding of what makes up pitch as well as the freqs involved. Ref: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/u11l2a.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Consider the unit analyzers in the ChucK music programming language: http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/#uana

Answer (score 0):

Audacity will help. If you want to use them from your program, you can check out their source code. http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/source

Note:First please download audacity to check if it has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where to start I would recommend you just buy sound forge or some other professional editing program, which already has the algorithms. If you're really determined then get out your physics book because thats where it'll come from. Finding the overall pitch of a sound is an calculus transformation. Other info about the sound, like tempo can be found with the help of impulse response filters and some AI. Unless you feel really dedicated, just buy a editor.

Update: if you really want to go for it [here's](http://pjwhams.co.uk/download/thesis.pdf) a great resource.

Comment: its a calculus transformation that is WIDELY implemented and easily done. Python has it in its numpy module. C++ has MANY implementations available. FFT's are ez enough to do nowadays that it shouldn't stop someone from really wanting to try.

Comment: FFT's are very easy to find but it's not just the fft that you need, you need AI to be able to understand the results of the fft.

Comment: He doesn't necessarily say what he's trying to do. If its a very specific thing he's trying to do, he doesn't need much AI if its done right.

Comment: it just seems like a lot of math, that has already been done. Audacity might do what he wants, I have an old, old version of sound forge that can do exactly what he wants. You can get an old version of sound forge on ebay for like $10, so it just doesn't seem worth the time and effort to me.

Comment: if its purely for 'informative' reasons, then yes, i too do not see a point. If he is trying to create this program (like for Android or Iphone), then he's going to need to know atleast what its going to take.